# Section 19 Munkres Topology, $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ vs $\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Question 7 in Munkres's Topology Reads:

"Let $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ consisting of all sequences that are 'eventually zero...'"

I am trying to understand what's the difference between $\mathbb{R}^\infty$  and $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. What does the superscript $\omega$ suggest about the space $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ ?

I believe $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ refers to the product topology (or Box Topology) of $\mathbb{R}$,
while $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ $\textit{is}$ $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, but also holds the property that any sequence is eventually zero...

Is this correct? I have not seen the formal definition of either of these and in this case, I believe the definition directly leads me to answer the problem:
" What is the closure of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ in the box and product topologies?"

Comment: The definition of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, "consisting of all sequences that are 'eventually zero", suggests that they have defined, or are going to define, $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ to allow $(1,1,1,...)$ to be in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, while not in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Ill take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is the product of denumberably many
copies of R with the product topology,
namely all sequences of real numbers.

$\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is just the sequences that are eventually 0.
Between these two spaces is the space of real
sequences that converge to zero.